# PHP count values in database and display in table

Tags: php

I am trying to count the various times a phrase is found in a database. An example phrase is 0p.3 where 0 would be incremented to also display 1p.3, 2p.3, etc up to 9p.3 in subsequent columns of a table. The function I have to count that is as follows:

```
$raw_data = $db->query("select * from $db_table");
$data = [];
foreach ($raw_data as $raw){
    $words = array_count_values(explode(" ", $raw['text']));
    foreach ($words as $word => $amount) {
        $data[$word] += $amount;
    }
}
```

To display this in the table, the following php is being used inside  tags to display for all of the columns. I am receiving a Notice: Undefined index: 9s.0 in /var/www/html/file.php on line 176 for every time the php function is called to display the data. I am stuck and not sure how to proceed.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <=9; $i++){
    echo "<td>".$data[$i."p.3"]."</td>";
  } ?>
```

Comment: check `$data` value by using `print_r( $data);` and show us .Also why don't you use `foreach()`?

Comment: what  is  key in for loop `p.3`?

Comment: here not key `9s.0`, Are you sure that you are displaying the correct code?

Comment: You don't fetch the result. If you're using MySQLi, you have to call [`$raw_data->fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your table generation code with this

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <=9; $i++){
    if(isset($data[$i."p.3"]))
    echo "<td>".$data[$i."p.3"]."</td>";
    else
    echo "<td>-</td>";
}
?>
```